# .net datareader changing a date within string/varchar returned from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

**Problem**

In trying to get the week end date, the VB.NET DbDataReader seems to be changing the date within a string that is returned back from the database.
Using 18-jan-2018 and 1-mar-2018 as the start and end dates respectively, I expect to get back the following strings from the database.

```
Week Ending 21/01/2018
Week Ending 28/01/2018
Week Ending 04/02/2018
Week Ending 11/02/2018
Week Ending 18/02/2018
Week Ending 25/02/2018
Week Ending 04/03/2018
```

On my local development system, I get back the correct dates as above. On other development systems and production systems I get back

```
Week Ending 22/01/2018
Week Ending 29/01/2018
Week Ending 05/02/2018
Week Ending 12/02/2018
Week Ending 19/02/2018
Week Ending 26/02/2018
Week Ending 05/03/2018
```

**Code**

The SQL stored procedure takes a start and end date from the .net front end. The values passed in are correct.

**SQL Stored Procedure**

```
SET @dteStartDate = CAST(@prmStartDate As smalldatetime)
SET @dteEndDate = CAST(@prmEndDate As smalldatetime)

DECLARE @MyTempTable TABLE (
        [tmpDate] [smalldatetime], 
        [NumReferrals] [int] NULL
    )

DECLARE @dteCurrent AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @NumReferrals AS INT


SELECT  @dteCurrent = dbo.fnGetEndOfWeek(@dteStartDate)


WHILE @dteCurrent <= dbo.fnGetEndOfWeek(@dteEndDate)
BEGIN
    --SELECT FROM DATA
    INSERT INTO @MyTempTable (tmpDate, NumReferrals) VALUES (@dteCurrent, @NumReferrals)
    SET @dteCurrent = DATEADD(Week, 1, @dteCurrent)
END


SELECT  NumReferrals as Referrals,
        'Week Ending ' + convert(nvarchar, tmpDate, 103) AS WeekEnding

FROM    @MyTempTable
```

**function fnGetEndOfWeek**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetEndOfWeek
(
    @prmInputDate smalldatetime

)

BEGIN
Declare @AddNumOfDay INT

    -- If input date is not Sunday, move it foward to Sunday
    -- 1 Sunday
    -- 2 Monday
    --  ...
    -- 7 Saturday

    SELECT @AddNumOfDay = CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @prmInputDate))
    WHEN '2' THEN '6'
    WHEN '3' THEN '5'
    WHEN '4' THEN '4'
    WHEN '5' THEN '3'
    WHEN '6' THEN '2'
    WHEN '7' THEN '1'
    WHEN '1' THEN '0'
    END

   RETURN DATEADD(d,@AddNumOfDay,@prmInputDate)
END
```

The results that come back from SQL Server are correct on all systems (Dev and Production.

**The .NET code is as follows :**

```
Dim dtSeriesData As New Data.DataTable

Using cmdGetSeries As SqlCommand = conLocal.CreateCommand()
    Using sqlSeries As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()

        cmdGetSeries.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdGetSeries.CommandText = sp
        For Each param As SqlParameter In sqlParams
            If Not param Is Nothing Then
                cmdGetSeries.Parameters.Add(param)
            End If
        Next

        Using dr As System.Data.Common.DbDataReader = cmdGetSeries.ExecuteReader()
            dtSeriesData.Load(dr) *
        End Using
    End Using
    cmdGetSeries.Parameters.Clear()
End Using
```

At the asterisk (`dtSeriesData.Load(dr)`), the rows of data are for some reason changed, even though it is a string.

**Question**

Why would this be happening? we are all using .NET 4.5, SQL Server 2014. Even Casting the returned SELECT as a varchar, or setting the temporary table column type as varchar instead of datetime yields the same result, the String is manipulated by .NET except on my local machine. Is there some .net setting that i've missed somewhere?

**EXTRA OUTCOMES FOLLOWING DISCUSSIONS IN COMMENTS**

Using the jQuery UI DatePicker controller for selecting start and end dates, the following is executed on SQL Server (by using sql profiler)

```
exec spGetGraphReferralsbyWeekAll @prmStartDate='18 Jan 2018',@prmEndDate='01 Mar 2018'
```

This procedure returns the following data in SSMS

```
Week Ending 21/01/2018
Week Ending 28/01/2018
Week Ending 04/02/2018
Week Ending 11/02/2018
Week Ending 18/02/2018
Week Ending 25/02/2018
Week Ending 04/03/2018
```

Using the DataSet Visualiser in Visual Studio for dtSeries.Indexes(0).Table brings back

```
Week Ending 22/01/2018
```

The `@@DATEFIRST` variable brings back `7` in SSMS on machines that display the correct result, and machines that don't.

Changing the DateTime property from `103` to `127` within the stored procedure brings back the same (correct) date `2018-01-21T00:00:00` on machines that work and machines that don't work. The date is still changed by the `dtSeriesData.Load` part of the application.

`conLocal` is NOT a persistent SQL Connection

`.AddWithValue` is NOT used for adding parameters.

Comment: What is the code to fill the temp table? Could it be culturally sensitive and that culture be set differently on different machines?

Comment: Can you return the values as datetime instead of date only? Might be an issue of different timezones leading to a few hours difference.

Comment: Colin, Grek, I don't believe it is a datetime issue. The stored procedure run on all machines returns the correct values in the temp table. the 'Week Ending' column is a varchar string, I don't see how Locales can affect this.

Comment: Because you might be sending in a start and end date that is in the client time zone which might be different from the servers time zone.

Comment: @AndrewMorton SELECT @@DateFirst brings back 7 on both my machine (which brings returns the correct string) and on another developers machine (which brings back the altered string)

Comment: The SP works correctly in SSMS.

Comment: Please show how you set the start and end date parameters in your code. I won't be satisfied until I see some explicit `Utc` specified value or explicit handling of local values.

Comment: @grek40 i've added extra output information into the question, and outcomes at various points of execution

Comment: What do you get when you replace the convert style `convert(nvarchar, tmpDate, 103)` with `convert(nvarchar, tmpDate, 127)` (ISO8601 with time zone Z: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ`)? If any timezone related stuff is involved, this should make it visible (compare program to SSMS)

Comment: @grek40 I get `Week Ending 2018-01-21T00:00:00`, my colleague who gets the incorrect result gets `Week Ending 2018-01-22T00:00:00` - thats just running it in SSMS and Frontend

Comment: Uhm... are you now saying that the procedure doesn't work in SSMS also for the colleague? I thought you checked that and eliminated it (*"The SP works correctly in SSMS"*)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I get the correct results on my machine, in both SSMS and Application. Other colleagues and Production servers get the correct results in SSMS and the incorrect result in `dtSeriesData.Load` part of the application

Comment: Can you query [`DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql)? It's the last thing I can think of :)

Comment: @kolin Is `conLocal` a persistent SQL connection? You should not do that; instead, create the connection, use it, dispose of it. Also, the body of `fnGetEndOfWeek` could be `RETURN  DATEADD(DAY, (8 - DATEPART(dw,@prmInputDate)) % 7, @prmInputDate);`, which also does not treat the number as a string. Finally, did you use `.AddWithValue` anywhere? That can mess things up.

Comment: @grek40 , yeah, that was done earlier in the comments. the result being 7 for all machines.

Comment: @AndrewMorton conLocal isn't a persistant connection, and .AddWithValue isn't used anywhere (i've previously had woes with that method before) I will also add that this is legacy code.

Comment: @kolin maybe you can update your question with the information that was discussed in the comments. It would help if you are 100% specific on the details. For example, you state you already checked the `DateFirst` thing, but I don't *know* whether you checked this from within the C# application on the server (where the problem occurs) as opposed to checking it in SSMS.

Comment: @kolin You can be sure that the *returned* strings are not being changed by .NET Framework code (how would it know to look at them, extract the date, add 1 day, and put the string on the front again?). Perhaps there is some code affecting `dtSeriesData`. What do you get if you read the data in VB in a loop instead of using the `.Load` method?

Comment: You still didn't clarify what's the result of querying `DateFirst` from code (you only clarified for SSMS, but the whole point is you have a difference between SSMS and code results...).  So what happens for `var com = connection.CreateCommand(); com.CommandText = "select @@datefirst"; var test = (byte)com.ExecuteScalar();` is the value of `test` consistent with your expectations on the machines where the results are bad?